# What does NDB do under the cover on key.get()?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am starting using NDB as it offers some very nice features and should be generally more optimized than when I implement by own caching layer.

However I do not understand all of what is going on for simple operations like key.get().
Appstats shows that during such operation, on a dev server that just started, 4 RPCs are made:

```
@434ms memcache.Get real=1ms api=0ms
@437ms memcache.Set real=1ms api=0ms
@438ms memcache.Get real=2ms api=0ms
@441ms datastore_v3.Get real=4ms api=0ms
```

How come we have 2 memcache.Get ops? Why does memcache.Set appear before datastore_v3.Get?
I use the default caching options.
Looking in ndb.context.get gives some insights but I'm still confused. The memcache.Set is made about a LOCK. but the two Get calls looks identical and why is there no Set right after the datastore Get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use @ndb.toplevel() around your top-level functions or WSGI application object?  It is a common problem that if you omit that, the actual Set call is never executed.  See http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=105 (follow the link to the group in comment 5!).

Comment: I saw that ticket but it was closed so I thought I would no longer need the topLevel thing... as it sounds odd to be forced to use it to have the caching work.

Comment: Works indeed better with it, thanks. There is now a 5th RPC call to Set the model to memcache. Looks like a lot of calls but I guess it's the price to have more consistent results...

Comment: I've fixed the issue in SDK 1.6.5 but that's not out yet.  The extra RPCs are only on the first get() -- subsequent get()s go straight to memcache.